# Swift class "MyClass" does not have a member Named "My_Var"

Tags: ios, swift

I created a class in Swift like below, but it gives error:

> 'ApiUrls.Type' does not have a member named 'webUrl'

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ApiUrls {

    let webUrl:NSString = "192.168.0.106:8888"
    var getKey:NSString = webUrl + NSString("dev/sys/getkey") // here comes the error ApiUrls.Type' does not have a member named 'webUrl

}
```

What's wrong in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize an instance property with the value of another property, because `self` is not available until all instance properties have been initialized.

Even moving the properties initialization in an initializer doesn't work, because `getKey` relies on `webUrl`, so `getKey` cannot be initialized until itself is initialized.

I see that `webUrl` is a constant, so maybe it's a good idea to make it a static property - classes don't support statics as of yet, so the best way is to use a private struct:

```
class ApiUrls {
    private struct Static {
        static let webUrl: String = "192.168.0.106:8888"
    }

    var getKey: String = Static.webUrl + "dev/sys/getkey"

}
```

Also, unless you have a good reason, it's better to use swift strings and not `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot initialise variables like that in the class definition.

Try declaring your variables as

```
let webUrl:NSString = "192.168.0.106:8888"
var getKey:NSString = ""
```

and add this in viewDidLoad

```
getKey = webUrl + NSString("dev/sys/getkey")
```

Comment: I m not extendin my Class from UIViewController. hence I cant override the didViewLoad metho thanks for BTW

Comment: You can do it in the class init() method then....same effect